# Ms Excel: Remove duplicate spaces and separate preceding character in the next cell

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have a raw text file wherein data in a column is separated by duplicate spaces. I wanted to remove

```
Name                              Version
a                                 b
```

How to separate Name and version and the succeeding rows in a separate cell.

Comment: Try Data, Data Tools, Text to Columns, Fixed width, Finish.

Comment: Try Data, Data Tools, Text to Columns, Delimited, Space, Finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Data, Data Tools, Text to Columns, Fixed width, Finish.

[image]

Try Data, Data Tools, Text to Columns, Delimited, Space, Finish.

[image]